# Filter Empty/Nothing Selected - Should it exclude or include all results?

Tags: filter, empty

On one hand, excluding all results isn't as useful to the user as including all results.

On the other hand, I think including all results may make the filter less intuitive.

Another consideration is multiple selection filters.  Often, a way to "select all" is convenient to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand what the **functionality of a Filter** is.

> The reason why a user would apply a filter is to weed out results that
>   they don't want.

**If no filter is applied, the user expects to see all the results.**

As far as the "showing all results seems non-intuitive" is concerned; that is a whole different use case on its own. That depends on how the results get shown. Is it a list that gets populated as soon as you open a certain page? Or does it get populated by a user when they use a *Search* functionality? But I don't want to get into it because it's not in the scope of this question.